# Another Reference Problem in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First I would like to say that this problem is merely cosmetic but it is starting to drive me a little insane and it is becoming a hassle to find the references that I need.

Anyway, I have created multiple COM references in .NET for VBA over the years and have registered them and used the .tlb files in Excel. Now I have a list of these references that I don't use. Actually, when I click them I get an message "Error in loading DLL".

I can only seem to find resources on how to remove references that are being used in the Excel program. Is there a program/code I can use to just get rid of all the references that don't work?